# Is it possible to increment a letter with a press of a button?/

Tags: java, increment

I want to increment alphabets in a text field with the press of a button.
Like if the text field is 'A' then the next letter should be 'B' after I press the button.
Is it possible?

Comment: Yes. It is possible.

Comment: Swing textfield? We need more details.

Comment: We also need to see your attempt and your description of what problem's you may be having with it.

Answer (score 2):

Without going into Java GUI with Swing etc, (RTM), here's a clue:

```
System.out.println((char) ('A'+1));
```

outputs B

Answer (score 0):

yes, you would get the current character's keycode, delete the character, increment the keycode by one and create that character.